# Add Property dynamically to the JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-ui, jsonresult

I would like to two add property Id and ButtonId to the exisiting json result. I have pasted the below js code for reference and I would like to pass the jsonresult to MVC controller. As of now it returns null. please help to proceed. Thanks.

my final result should look like this

> json{"Groups":{"Id":"2","ButtonId":"1142","1186","1189"},
>   {"Id":"3","ButtonId":"1171","1173","1174","1175","1176","1187"},
>   {"Id":"4","ButtonId":"1177","1178","1179"}} etc..

```js
 var btnlist = {Groups: {Id:"", ButtonId: ""}};                
  $.each($(".buttonData"), function (index, value) {
   var values = value.id.split(':');                            
   grpid = values[0].split('-')[1];
   btnid = values[1].split('-')[1];
   
    console.log('grpid=' + grpid + ' btnid=' + btnid);

    if (typeof (btnlist['Groups'][grpid]) == 'undefined') {
        btnlist['Groups'][grpid] = [];
      }      
        btnlist['Groups'][grpid].push(btnid);    
    });    

  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("Home", "Menu")",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(btnlist) ,        
        success: function (result) {        
        console.log('json' + JSON.stringify(btnlist));
        console.debug(result);
        },
        error: function (request, error) {      
        console.debug(error);
         }
      });
```

This is the json result before pushing into the multidimensional array
[image: result]

The json result, where the properties Id and ButtonId is inserted behind.
[image: json result]

null result passed to the controller
[image: controller]

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify(btnlist)` as far as I know there's no need to stringify your JSON before sending to an MVC controller. This may be what's confusing it. Just do `data: btnlist` and see if that works

Comment: @ADyson I tried doing data:btnlist, it returns parse error, and doesnt hit  the breakpoint

Comment: what does the error say exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With assistance of my colleague, the desired output is as below. This is for other programmers who face similar issue with JSON array. Thanks.

```
         var btnlist = [];
              btngrps = $('.btn-sort-container');
              $.each(btngrps, function(k, v) {
                btnarr = {};

                gid = $(this).attr('id');
                grpid = gid.split('-')[1];
                btnarr.Id = gid.split('-')[1];

                btnobjs = $(v).find('.buttonData');
                if (btnobjs.length) {
                  btnarr['btnId'] = [];
                  $.each(btnobjs, function(bk, bv) {

                    btnid = $(bv).attr('id').split('-')[2];

                    btnarr['btnId'].push($(bv).attr('id').split('-')[2]);

                  });
                  console.debug(btnarr);
                  btnlist.push(btnarr);
                }
              });
              console.debug(btnlist);
```

Output on console

[image: ]]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ3Dy.png